# $k^t=8$, $t^k=9$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I have $k^t=8$ and $t^k=9$.
The solutions are $2^3=8$ and $3^2=9$ but I Can't think of a **way** to solve it without knowing the answers.
I've tried $t=\frac{ln(8)}{ln(k)}$ and then $(\frac{ln(8)}{ln(k)})^k = 9$ so I can have only one variable. But it didn't work.

I want a method that doesn't lean on "guessing", so I can also use it for large numbers such as $k^t=729$ and $t^k=19683$ (k=9, t=3).

Comment: Are you trying to solve for natural numbers $k$ and $t$? Or are they real variables?

Comment: I already know that t=3 and k=2, hence they are both real and natural.

Comment: If you know they must be integers, it is direct, since $8$ is a power of $2$ and $9$ a power of $3$ so $k=2$ and $t=3$.

Comment: Can you read my comment on the answer? what if the numbers were larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\ln 8 = 3 \ln 2$, so you can write $ \frac{3\ln 2}{ \ln k} = \sqrt[k] 9$, then $k=2$ is an easy guess. Moreover you can see that the graphs of $y=\frac{3\ln 2}{ \ln k}$ and $y = \sqrt[k] 9$ only have one intersection by monotony.

Probably the problem can not be explicitly solved for random numbers, so you must be happy for the lucky shot in guessing the easy k.

EDIT: I underestimated the verification of monotony, maybe it's not that simple but probably should work something like that.

Comment: So you say that if the numbers were larger (yet k,t are natural) I couldn't solve it? for example k^t=729, t^k=19683 (k=9, t=3).

Comment: Not that you can't, but surely not in an explicit way. I don't think the number chosen matters.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks!

Comment: Try the command plot 9^{1/x} and  ln(8)/ln(x) for x >0 in https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1000%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D+and++ln%2841%29%2Fln%28x%29+for+x+%3E0 to convince yourself that the numbers does not matters, then you can verify that the two functions alway intersect once, since one of the two has faster decaying at infinity.

Comment: Thanks! I will.